# Does any C/C++ preprocessor produce an accurate .i file?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

When I generate a preprocessor .i output file from a C or C++ source code file using the /P command line option in any version of a Microsoft compiler, the resulting code will sometimes not compile at all even though the original C/C++ source code compiled fine.  For example, when I compile the following code directly there are no problems:

```
#define VALUE -1

int main(void)
{
    int x = -VALUE;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the preprocessor output file "equivalent" is the following, which is obviously not equivalent and is not going to compile:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = --1;
    return 0;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there some other Microsoft option I should be using to get a .i file that is always a correct representation of the original?
2. Are there any compilers whose preprocessor output files are always a correct representation of the original?

If I can't use Microsoft for this my second choice would be minGW, and then clang for Windows.  I just want something that produces a correct .i file.

Thanks

Comment: @KenWhite: actually, the first code does compile, and even produces the expected value (`-VALUE == 1`). I tried it in several non-Microsoft compilers. For example, [this one](https://ideone.com/qonPKU) and [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30991b5fc766abf6).

Comment: When I run the first code through "g++ -E ./test.cpp", I see that it puts a space between the two minuses:  int x = - -1;

Comment: `int x = -VALUE;` is the same as `int x = - -1;` ie `int x = -(-1);` [See this](https://ideone.com/NvnabQ)

Comment: The preprocessor tokenizes its input.  The `-` before `VALUE` is a token; then VALUE is a token that is expanded to two tokens — a `-` and a `1`.  So there are 3 tokens on the RHS of the assignment when handled by the compiler.  The output from the preprocessor as text is not as accurate as it could be.  Note that `--1` written directly would be (is) invalid because of the "maximal munch" rule — you can't decrement a constant.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. I've deleted my comment. Should  have tested before posting. It's been a long time since I've worked with C or C++.

Comment: You should find that MinGW (`gcc`) and Clang both produce usable output in their `.i` files.

Comment: This is one of those (many) times when the value of a macro should be surrounded by parens

Comment: @user3629249: While it is certainly a good general rule to parenthesize macro values consisting of more than 1 token, have you ever encountered or can you think of a case other than a defective preprocessor where not parenthesizing the simple negation of a numeric literal could ever cause a problem of any kind?  Regardless, programmers shouldn't have to program around product defects as basic and long-lived as this one.

Comment: @BenevolentDeity,  The important thing to remember is that a 'macro' is ONLY a text replacement tool.    It does not perform anything else.  The programmer has to assure that their macros result is compilable code

Comment: @user3629249 You state the obvious in that a programmer must always assure that his/her code is compilable.  However, a macro must be thought of as a bit more than a blind "copy & paste" text replacement tool.  As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, its replacement list must also be tokenized before replacement, which MSVC did not do when creating my .i file but did do during the direct compile.